# How to link BCWP to a customized column I created for physical percent complete

Tags: ms-project

As physical % complete does not roll-up summary tasks, I created a column called 'physical percent complete'. I think I need to link this column to Budgeted Cost of Work Performed (BCWP), just so I can have a more accurate Equivalent Annual Cost (EAC) based on the physical percent complete.

I have tried creating a new column and adding the formula:

> baseline cost * physical percent complete

though it does not want to work. My plan was to then create another column for 'estimated at completion' based on the result from previous formula.

Does anyone have an idea on how I can achieve a more accurate EAC based on the customised column for physical percent complete?

Thank you.

Comment: Had to guess on the acronyms. If they're incorrect, please correct them.

Comment: The acronyms are the actual field names in MS Project and as such should not be changed. FYI: EAC = Estimate At Completion.

Answer (score 0):

`BCWP` is a non-customizable field in MS Project. However, you can use a customizable field, such as `Cost1` to add a formula that uses your other customized field, 'physical percent complete'.

Presuming you used `Number1` for that field, enter this as the formula in `Cost1`:

```
[Baseline Cost]*[Number1]
```

Note that even if you override the label for `Number1` to say 'physical percent complete', the formula still references the underlying field name, `Number1`.

Answer (score -2):

I have a simple answer - stop using MS Project - it is anti-Agile!

If you are doing detailed planning more than 1 week ahead and trying to track percentage done, you are not being Agile.

Comment: Commenting to the question is a better way of providing your view instead of writing it as an answer.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/20818)